# DataGridView row: Semi-transparent selection or row border on selection

Tags: forms

I have a DataGridView where the background of each row is different depending on the data bound item. Though, when I select a row, I can no longer see its original background color.

To solve this, I have thought of two solutions:

I can make the selections semi-transparent, making it possible to see if two selected rows have different background colors.

Or; I can remove the selection colors entirely, and draw a border around the selected rows.

What option is easier and how can I do this?

It's a WinForm app.

Edit: I ended up with the code in my original post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448945/datagridview-row-semi-transparent-selection-or-row-border-on-selection

Comment: This sounds like a programming issue, more than a UI issue. It requires knowledge of 'WinForm' and 'DataGridView'. I suggest you ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448945/datagridview-row-semi-transparent-selection-or-row-border-on-selection

;)

Comment: IMO, you received bad advice over in that question ("post it on ui.stackexchange") because it's a programming question; you asked "What option is easier and how can I do this".

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion - I was thinking more in a way: "What would the end user be most comfortable with"... I misunderstood the question - apologies @Jim Carragher and others..

Comment: This is a colour and indication of selection question, not a programming question. It's a good question too, so +1. Oh, and welcome to ui SE site Jim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction when I read that "the background of each row is different depending on the data bound item" was *Oh no, I hope that he's talking of one or two colors at most* !  :-)

Rather than solving your selection problem, I suggest that you make it a non-problem and make it go away.  I would do that by adding a separate column to provide the same information that the background color is intended to represent.  Not only would it be cleaner, IMO, but it would also provide the following advantages:

- You can sort by "status" (or whatever the colored background is intended to represent)
- If you don't have a lot of different colors, you might be able to use shapes, which is very helpful for the [color blind](http://curiouschap.com/2010/01/color-oracle/).
- You can combine a visual with numeric information.  The following screen snapshot shows progress bars in a column, but you can use a similar approach to represent what your background color is currently trying to achieve.

  [image]

Is there a reason that you *must* use background color?

Comment: +1 for the introduction of accessibility for colour blind users.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I will probably add a new column to present the information needed.

Comment: Well, I ended up with a semi-transparent selection color as you can see in my edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448945/datagridview-row-semi-transparent-selection-or-row-border-on-selection

Comment: @Hisham: how did you create the interface in the screenshot?